# Oracle - python cx_oracle - include "exec schema.get" before data extract

Tags: python, oracle, toad

I am newbie to oracle and I am trying to make a connection from python to an oracle table.

I can use Toad for oracle to access to the data of one table.  I am running the same SQL command through python and I get the "DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist".  I have search a lot and still do not know what the issue is:

I setup my connection:

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect(<user>,<password>,<database name>)
print("Database version:", con.version)
```

Successful connection

I set my current schema

```
con.current_schema = 'schema_name'
```

and

```
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute('select du.cfile_id from table_name du')
```

This throws an error of:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-195-f3f5aacf8431> in <module>()
----> 1 cursor.execute('select du.cfile_id from brwr_tau_to_du_log du')

DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Same query with same credential is working fine if I use "Toad for oracle".  Note that I require to put "exec schema.PKG_DVS_ACCESS.get" before running my data extract on Toad.  How should I include the command to my python code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To call PL/SQL procedures and packages in cx_Oracle use `callproc`:

```
cursor.callproc('myproc')
```

If the PL/SQL procedure has parameters, you will have to bind data values.

```
myvar = cur.var(int)
cur.callproc('myproc', (123, myvar))
print(myvar.getvalue())
```

Take a look at the [cx_Oracle tutorial](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples/tutorial).

Update: A new [blog post](https://learncodeshare.net/2018/07/30/execute-pl-sql-calls-with-cx_oracle/) from Oracle talks more about using PL/SQL with cx_Oracle.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.